# Convert rows to columns and one hot encoding in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
customer_id | date     | category
1           | 2017-2-1 | toys
2           | 2017-2-1 | food
1           | 2017-2-1 | drinks
3           | 2017-2-2 | computer
2           | 2017-2-1 | toys
```

And I want to convert this dataframe into this:

```
customer_id | toys | food | drinks | computer 
1           | 1    | 0    | 1      | 0        
2           | 1    | 1    | 0      | 0
3           | 0    | 0    | 0      | 1
```

I want to group by customer_id and date, one hot encoding the categories to show if that customer purchased things in those categories in the same day.

I know the `groupby()` method and I tried with `df.groupby(['customer_id', 'date'])` but that doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out how to make values in `'category'` my new columns.

I've looked at the post about `pivot_table()`, but I can't find any information on bounding each row to be within the same day

Thank you.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.customer_id, df.category)`

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for reply, how can I make sure that each row is from the day?